# Access enclosed variables through outer function called within closure

Tags: r, closures

The following code is supposed to change the value of the enclosed variable `some.var` calling the function `set.var`. The latter calls itself the outer function `g`, whose environment is changed to the parent environment of `set.var`

```
new.obj <- function(){
some.var = NULL

set.var <- function(...) {
    environment(g) <- parent.frame()
    g(x="some.var", ...)
}

get.var <- function(){some.var} 

return(list(set.var=set.var, get.var=get.var)) 
}

g <- function(x) assign(x,1)
```

However, `obj<-new.obj(); obj$set.var(); obj$get.var()` returns `NULL`. What goes wrong here and how can the behaviour be fixed?

The reason why I am considering this construction is, that I would like to reuse the code within `g` in different closures. Hence, it should be placed outside of these.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Right now this really doesn't make a lot of sense. What's `g()` supposed to be doing with a parameter named "par" that doesn't exist? Why is `g` outside the enclosure? Why aren't you setting the environment in the `assign()` call rather than the function calling it? What environment do you think `parent.frame()` should be pointing do?

Comment: `par` is a typo, changed it to `x`. The idea is the following: Having similar enclosing functions `new.obj2`, `new.obj3`, etc. one could reuse `g` with different parameters, instead of defining the function for each closure separately. I cannot put the environment into `g`, since the function does not know out of which environment it will be called. `parent.frame()` should point in my opinion to the environment created by the closure.

Comment: `parent.frame` gives you the environment where a function was called from, not where it was defined. Maybe you want `parent.env(environment())`? But even then, anything `g` does by default only happens in it's own enclosure. Functions aren't meant to change values outside their own scopes (proper functions shouldn't have side effects). Maybe you want `assign(x,1,inherits=TRUE)`? But that's super specific to `assign()`. I still don't understand what problem you are trying to solve with this unusual construction. It seems to try to break all of R's scoping rules.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are making things more complicated than necessary. Take a look at this example and comment if you need to achieve something that this cannot do:

```
do_the_job <- function(x) {
    return(x * 1000)
}

wrapper_function <- function(y) {
    return( do_the_job(y) )
}

my_value <- 5
my_new_value <- wrapper_function(my_value)
```

Comment: Yes, it is more complicated than necessary, but on purpose. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what I'm doing here myself.

I hope it helps/inspires you:

```
new.obj <- function(){
    env1 <- new.env()
    env1$some.var = NULL

    f <- function() {
        environment(g) <- parent.frame()
        g(x="some.var", envir = env1)
    }

    get.var <- function(){ env1$some.var }

    return(list(f=f, get.var=get.var)) 
}

g <- function(x, ...) assign(x, "hihi_changed", envir = ...)
```

1. `obj<-new.obj(); obj$get.var()` null is returned as we expect.
2. `obj$f(); obj$get.var()`        function g is called eventually that changes `some.var`.

My trick is to add the variable `some.var` to a new environment and always refer to that `env1` environment.

So in function g(), always use the ellipsis to refer to the new.obj environment `env1`, where currently `some.var` lives.

Hope this keeps you going.

Comment: This works indeed, thanks! I am wondering whether there is a more elegant way to achieve this